# Make Linux ext2 file system disk image

Tags: filesystems, block, inode, ext2, diskimage

How do you construct a file system disk image and then look at its disk layout in bitmap files? How do you add directories to it?

I've used *mkfs.ext2* on a file that I made using [dd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_%28Unix%29), but I'm not sure if it’s done correctly.

I need to be able to see the inodes and inode table and see how they relate to the blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dd`, `mkfs.ext{2,3,4}`, and `losetup` to create a disk image, a file system and mount the device.

Next, you may want to explore and learn using [debugfs - ext2/ext3/ext4 file system debugger](http://linux.die.net/man/8/debugfs). This has a lot of commands, `bmap`, `dump`, `dump_extents` and many more.

Additionally, if you want to read the file system meta data and debug, it would be good idea to explore the `tune2fs`, and `e2image` commands which would require a good understanding of file system internals.